# swift different textview url

Tags: swift, url, textview, tableview

I have a tableview.
Each cell opens a new ViewController and  loads a .txt file to a textview from my github repo. 
But now i want to make each cells to load a different .txt file from the same repo.
So like the first cell loads the first.txt, the second loads the second.txt and so on
is this even possible?
It would be like a news reader app where you click on a title and can read the article.

Here is my current code which is bad but im a beginner :(

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let content = self.downloadContent()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.myTextView.text = content
        }
    }

}

func downloadContent() -> String {
    var data : Data!
    data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SiposPtr/umszkiapp/master/cikk2.txt")!)
    let data_str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    return data_str!
}
```

I upload my files to a new github repo so you can see the whole stuff:
https://github.com/SiposPtr/stackoverflow

Comment: In a first quick look I can see that you are sending the TableData[indexPath.row] to the ViewController as a title, which is wrong because you need to send another information. Perhaps you could get the cell text (if it contains the name of the file to load) and send it to the ViewController to load there.

Comment: Also that when i click on a cell it doesnt send the text to the title it remains blank just after i clicked a new cell. and maybe this is bc what you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please check if this is working?

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var TableData: Array<String> = Array<String>()
var currentCell: String?
var selectedValue: String?
var numberOfFileToLoad: Int = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    get_data_from_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SiposPtr/umszkiapp/master/cimek.json")
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TableData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 2;

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 90.0;
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedValue = TableData[indexPath.row]
    numberOfFileToLoad = indexPath.row + 1
}

func get_data_from_url(_ link:String)
{
    let url:URL = URL(string: link)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {

            return
        }

        self.extract_json(data!)

    })

    task.resume()
}

func extract_json(_ data: Data) {

    let json: Any?

    do
    {
        json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    }
    catch
    {
        return
    }

    guard let data_list = json as? NSArray else
    {
        return
    }

    if let hir_lista = json as? NSArray {
        for i in 0 ..< data_list.count
        {
            if let hir_obj = hir_lista[i] as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let cim_nev = hir_obj["cim"] as? String
                {
                    if let hir_code = hir_obj["datum"] as? String
                    {
                        TableData.append(cim_nev + "\n(" + hir_code + ")")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

// ez működik, de a run utáni első cikknek üres a titléje és akk csúszik minden cím eggyel
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoSentences"{
        let nextViewController = segue.destination as! HirNezetViewController
        nextViewController.title = selectedValue
        print(selectedValue)
        nextViewController.numberOfFileToLoad = numberOfFileToLoad
        print(numberOfFileToLoad)
    }
}

@IBAction func reloadButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "A cikkeket újratöltöttem", message: "Kattints a gombra az eltüntetéshez", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Rendben", style: .default, handler: { action in
    })
    alert.addAction(ok)
    get_data_from_url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SiposPtr/umszkiapp/master/cimek.json")
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}

import UIKit

class HirNezetViewController: UIViewController {

var data:String!
var content: String?
var numberOfFileToLoad: Int = 1

@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let content = self.downloadContent()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.myTextView.text = content
        }
    }
}

func downloadContent() -> String {
    var data : Data!
    data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SiposPtr/umszkiapp/master/cikk\(String(numberOfFileToLoad)).txt")!)
    let data_str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    return data_str!
}
}
```

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Here you are the 3 files (2 classes and the Storyboard): https://github.com/JordiGamez/sipos-peter-sof @SiposPéter

Comment: I have edited my reply with an screenshot of the Storyboard, so you can check the differences (but in the repo there is the Storyboard code, so you can copy and paste). Regards.

Comment: And finally I have added a codeReview folder with some code review, to prevent your app from crashing and more best practices regarding Swift 4 :)

Comment: And I finally found the error in the UI. The problem was in the Storyboard. you should create a Segue from TableViewController to ViewController, not from TableViewCell to ViewController. Just copy and past my Storyboard code and check it :) Regards and good weekend!